# How can I obtain timing data from a MIDI file?

Tags: midi

I have a bunch of MIDI files which I need to process. For each of these, I have to find the exact millisecond certain chords began. How can I go about doing this? The libraries I've found so far haven't been all that helpful.

Is there a way to just print a list of notes and timestamps of a MIDI file?

Comment: I was hoping for a general tool or program. Programming-wise, Python, Java, or C.

Comment: So do you want to do it in [lang], or want to find software to do it for you?

Comment: Either, though the latter is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to print a list of notes and timestamps would be to use a MIDI to text conversion program. Googling 'midi to text' yields a few - for example, mf2t. However, MIDI files do not store timestamps of events in seconds or milliseconds, but rather delta times in ticks - try googling 'midi file delta time'.

Your choice is probably between:

- using a MIDI to text program, parsing the text output and doing the conversion to milliseconds yourself - perhaps using e.g. Excel
- using a MIDI library (for suggestions, tell us what language you're coding in) to read the note events and converting them to milliseconds directly, avoiding the text parsing step